# tagify whitelist for objects with duplicate names

Tags: javascript, discord

I asked this yesterday, but I didn't really get a solution, and after thinking more, I'm still unsure about what I can do to get by this issue.

```html
<script>
    var input = document.querySelector('input[name=tags-outside]');
    let guildRoles = []
    let guildIds = []
    guild_roles = {{ guild_roles|tojson }};
    guild_roles.map(e => {
        guildRoles.push(e["name"])
        guildIds.push(e["id"])
    })
    new Tagify(input, {
    whitelist: guildRoles,
    userInput: false
    })
</script>
```

I was originally thinking of having two arrays, one for ID, one for names, but this isn't really a good solution.

I have a dropdown list using tagify, and the user needs to select a discord role from this dropdown. Each role has a unique identifier in the array of objects, it resembers something like this:

```js
0: {color: 0, hoist: false, icon: null, id: "754852776550596638", managed: false, name: "role5"}
1: {color: 0, hoist: false, icon: null, id: "654852776550596638", managed: false, name: "role6"}
```

Each role can have the same name. So i need to be able to link up the ID to the role name, so that if the user selects a role, it won't use the wrong one since two roles can have the same name.

However, because `whitelist` only accepts an array, I do not know how I can link these IDs to their linked role names.

Any solutions would be very very helpful as I am clueless to how I can get around this...

An example of the dropdown can be found here:
https://gyazo.com/a7d691db9228cb1b61da0920f1561e57

Comment: Are the double curly braches for like `guild_roles = {{ guild_roles|tojson }};` intentional?

Comment: Instead of the `map` you are better off using `forEach` since map returns a new array (which you aren't using).

Comment: Why not an array of objects that has your role and id? I've never used tagify but looking at their [documentation](https://github.com/yairEO/tagify) it looks to be acceptable. Search for `Example whitelist:` on the page. The first one is an array of objects.

Comment: Thanks for all of the suggestions guys. :)

Also, Yes this line is intentional. Its `jinja` which allows you to pass variables through html templates in a flask webapp.
`guild_roles = {{ guild_roles|tojson }}; `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure this all according to the [docs](https://yaireo.github.io/tagify/).

Since you have duplicate keys, it is important to use the ID as value and not the name. In order to still show the name as text for the tags and also to be able to search for them, You need to set `tagTextProp`, in the top level object. In the dropdown, you need to set `mapValueTo` and `searchKeys`.

Something along these lines:

```js
const guildRoles = [{
    color: 0,
    hoist: false,
    icon: null,
    id: "754852776550596638",
    managed: false,
    name: "role5"
  },
  {
    color: 0,
    hoist: false,
    icon: null,
    id: "654852776550596638",
    managed: false,
    name: "role6"
  },
  {
    color: 0,
    hoist: false,
    icon: null,
    id: "343439489384938439",
    managed: false,
    name: "role6"
  }
]

const input = document.querySelector('[name=roles]')

tagify = new Tagify(input, {
  whitelist: guildRoles.map(({ id, name }) => ({ value: id, name })),
  enforceWhitelist: true,
  tagTextProp: 'name',
  dropdown: {
    enabled: 1,
    position: 'name',
    mapValueTo: 'name',
    highlightFirst: true,
    searchKeys: ['name'],
  },
  callbacks: {
    add: ({ detail: { data }}) => console.log(data)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@yaireo/tagify"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@yaireo/tagify/dist/tagify.polyfills.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/@yaireo/tagify/dist/tagify.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<input name='roles' placeholder="Add Roles">
```